# Getting "error: expected ']' before ';' token" when declaring an array in C

Tags: c, producer-consumer

I'm writing a Producer-Consumer solution but I keep getting "error: expected ']' before ';' token" when declaring "buffer_item buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];". I'm not quite sure what to do?

This is my buffer.h file:

```
typedef int buffer_item;

#define BUFFER_SIZE 5;
```

buffer.c file

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "buffer.h"

buffer_item buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

void *producer(void *param);
void *consumer(void *param);
//etc..
```

Comment: should be `#define BUFFER_SIZE 5` without the semicolon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macros are string replacing, so

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 5;
buffer_item buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

will become

```
buffer_item buffer[5;];
```

and you have extra semicolon after the number of elements.

You should use

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 5
```

(without semicolon) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the semicolon when you define your constant

```
   #define BUFFER_SIZE 5

    ....
```